# How can setConsumerRebalanceListener get the calling ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener instance?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Maybe this is a naive question but it somhow stuck me there for some time. Please bear with me.

I have a class DataConsumer.java that implements `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener`:

```java
@Component
public class DataConsumer implements ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener {
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        // seek offsets based on a given timestamp
    }
    @KafkaListener(topics = "dataTopic", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    receive(ConsumerRecord payload) {}
}
```

So in order for `onPartitionsAssigned` to work, i need to call `setConsumerRebalanceListener` in the `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` method which is defined in another class like this:

```java
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConsumerRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConsumerRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(____________);
    // rest part omitted
}
```

My question is about this `____________` part above. What shall i put there?

In my understanding, method `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` is called when we initialize the `@KafkaListener` container in DataConsumer class, so meaning there is already an existing DataConsumer instance to hold the `@kafkaLister`. How can i pass that already existing DataConsumer instance to `setConsumerRebalanceListener` function?

All the sample code snippets I can search out are like below:

```java
setConsumerRebalanceListener(new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
    //override the functions
})
```

But isn't this creating a new instance? If I put `new DataConsumer()` it will lose some status in the existing instance (e.g. the timestamp to seek offsets) so this can't work.

Comment: @Gary Russell  Can you help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `DataConsumer` as a `@Bean` (instead of using `@Component`) then you can inject your bean there.

However, this is the wrong mechanism to use in this case.

Implement `ConsumerSeekAware` instead - the container will automatically detect that your listener implements that and will call its `onPartitionsAssigned`.

See [Seeking to a Specific Offset](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Gary. If I implement `ConsumerSeekAware`, is there a way to get consumer in `onPartitionsAssigned` so I can perform `offsetsForTimes`? We use version 2.1.10 where `seekToTimestamp` is not available.

Comment: 2.1.x is no longer supported; if you can't upgrade to a more recent supported version for some reason, you will have to use the first technique that I described above.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I solved this with a temporary workaround, but still thinking version upgrade could be a better way for future.

Comment: BTW, you can leave it as a `@Component` and then `public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConsumerRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener listener) {...}`

Comment: This perfectly solved my problem! I was thinking `kafkaListenerContainerFactory()` is required by Spring so can't be changed, but apparently param list is not fixed. Thanks Gary for pointing that out.